# Issue using custom volume with jsreport Docker image on Windows

Tags: jsreport

I'm trying to use the official docker image with my own jsreport config file (so that I can use the http module).

I'm on Windows and my working folder is c:\code\jsreport.

I've created a folder under my working folder named `jsreport-home` and created a file named `prod.config.json` in there.

I then execute

```
docker run  -p 8080:5488 -v "c:\code\jsreport\jsreport-home:/jsreport" jsreport/jsreport
```

I can see a `data` folder created in the mounted volume folder, so I believe that I've mapped it correctly, however jsreport throws this error on it's initialization.

```
error: Failed to load collection settings Error: Failed to flush to storage`enter code here`
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong or should I raise this as an issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Update: It works fine on my Mac - sudo docker run -d -p 5488:5488  -v ~/code/jsreport/jsreport-home:/jsreport jsreport/jsreport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is bug in the [nedb](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb) lib providing the file system store implementation in jsreport. It doesn't like if the file system is from windows and the runtime from linux.

You can try jsreport v2 beta, which has re-implemented file system store.

```
docker run  -p 8080:5488 -v "c:\temp3:/jsreport" jsreport/jsreport:2.0.0-beta
```

Or if you just need to change some config values, you can pass them as environment variables:

```
docker run  -p 8080:5488 -e scripts_allowedModules=* jsreport/jsreport
```

Comment: Thanks Jan. I guess that I can work around it by running a Linux VM on my Windows box and hosting there.  Also, thank you for a fantastic product! You guys have really done an amazing job!